# Using timer in python for a basic game

Tags: python-3.x, timer

I have to create this basic game for a high school project. I'm new to the timer in python. My code is as follows:

```
import random
from threading import Timer

score = -1
directions = ["RIGHT", "LEFT", "UP", "DOWN"]
accdirection=random.choice(directions)

def timeOut():
    out_of_time = "yes"
    print("TESTING ")

while accdirection:
     TimeLimit = 1   
     score = score + 1    
     accdirection=random.choice(directions)
     print(accdirection)

     out_of_time = "no" 

     t=Timer(TimeLimit,timeOut)
     t.start()

     fast = input()

     if out_of_time == "yes":
         accdirection = None

     if accdirection in directions:
         t.cancel()


         if accdirection == "RIGHT":
             if fast == "d":
                 accdirection = random.choice(directions)
             else:
                 accdirection = None
                 print("Oops, you clicked the wrong key.")


         elif accdirection == "LEFT":
             if fast == "a":
                 accdirection = random.choice(directions)
             else:
                 accdirection = None
                 print("Oops, you clicked the wrong key.")


         elif accdirection == "UP":
             if fast == "w":
                 accdirection = random.choice(directions)
             else:
                 accdirection = None
                 print("Oops, you clicked the wrong key.")


         elif accdirection == "DOWN":

             if fast == "s":
                 accdirection = random.choice(directions)
             else:
                 accdirection = None
                 print("Oops, you clicked the wrong key.")

     else:
         print("Oof, too slow!")
         accdirection = None





print("Your score is:", score)
```

The function of the code is that python outputs a direction, and then the user has to input w, a, s or d. If they get the wrong key, the game is over and they have lost. This part works fine.
When the time runs out it prints out "TESTING" which I have done simply to test if it even goes to the timeOut function. However, it feels like the value of out_of_time seems to always stay the same: "no" in this case. Therefore, the value for accdirection isn't able to reset to None to break the loop. I'm sorry if most of the code is just useless to my question. Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `out_of_time = "yes"` in the `timeOut` function, but never return the updated value of `out_of_time`.

And `out_of_time` is initially set in the global namespace, so indicate that, and you should get your expected behavior:

```
def timeOut():
    global out_of_time
    out_of_time = "yes"
    print("TESTING ")
    return out_of_time
```